# VB.net How to hide dialogue without close the application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-embedded-compact

I have problem about `close()` or `dispose()` function with my barcode reader (Windows Embedded Compact 7). In this case I can only `hide()` form.

I tried to show `Form2` as dialogue but after I clicked the close button (to hide this form and go back to `Form1`) It made all of my application close

In Form1 (Main):

```
Public Sub showForm2()

    Dim secForm As New Form2

    secForm.ShowDialog()

End Sub
```

In Form2:

```
'close button  

Private Sub closebt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles closebt.Click 

    Me.Hide() 

End Sub
```

Comment: no reason why it would close.

Comment: @SSpoke It cause message received from Windows Message amount increase every time I enter the "scan form". Ex. First time I enter the form and scan, I recieve only one barcode message (from batch by `WndProc`) then I press back or change form then re-enter the scan form again I will received 2 messages per one scan, next time It will be 3, 4, 5 . . . messages. about this problem I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Form can't be hidden if it is shown as Dialog. If you want to hide the form then use form.show() rather than form.ShowDialog(). Also here is a link

```
    http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?759061-How-can-i-hide-my-second-form-dialog-without-bliking-form-not-closing-my-first-form
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to properties page of the project. In the Application tab, there is a setting:

- **Shutdown mode**

  - When startup form closes
  - When last form closes

Choose "When last form closes" to prevent closing the application when your main form closes.

Comment: I can't set Shutdown mode. It's not in the application setting.

Comment: It's not application settings, It's project properties. Right click on project and select properties. In the application tab you will find it.

Comment: Did you find it?

Comment: No, I have only "Assembly name, Root namespace, Application type, Icon: and Startup object".

Comment: At the bottom of the page, there are 3 dropdowns. The middle one.

Answer (score -1):

in the index form add in form closing the fallow code:

> Form1.Dispose()